# Can't extract zipped .csv file from API response and upload it to Google Sheets

Tags: python, csv, google-sheets, url, zip

I have a download url stored in `report_url` variable. Report URL looks like this.

> https://marketplace.walmartapis.com/v3/reports/getReport/item-performance-report/ItemPerformanceReport_10001043268_2023-02-22T070630.037000.zip?sv=2021-08-06&se=2023-02-22T07%3A41%3A58Z&sr=b&sp=r&sig=9iDSwHc27ViCRlY0Q56WTYA3t1YUAtSE1wl3kqQFRvg%3D

I want to extract .csv file in this zip file and upload it to Google Sheets. It is throwing me `AttributeError: 'str' object has no attribute 'content'` error. Here is my code. How can I extract it and upload the report to google sheets?

```py
from google.colab import auth        
from gspread_dataframe import get_as_dataframe, set_with_dataframe
import gspread
import gspread_dataframe as gd
import zipfile
import io
from google.auth import default

auth.authenticate_user()
creds, _ = default()
        
gc = gspread.authorize(creds)

response = wm.send_request(method, download_url, params=None, body=None, json=None, request_headers=None)
print(response)
report_url=response["downloadURL"]
print(report_url)
       
file_zip = zipfile.ZipFile(io.BytesIO(report_url.content))
file_csv = file_zip.open(file_zip.namelist()[0])
data = csv.reader(io.TextIOWrapper(file_csv))
    
sheet = gc.open("Report").worksheet("Item_Performance")
sheet.clear()
sheet.insert_rows(data)

print("Report uploaded to Google Sheets")
```

Comment: Maybe include a complete code example, `wm` is not defined in your script. Maybe check the documentation of the response as to how to access the data that is being returned by the API. The error is stating that the content attribute does not exist on the variable `report_url`

Comment: I'm confused as to what you think `content` is supposed to be. You have a URL as a string as `report_url`. You'll have to download the file at that URL first.

Comment: Hi :) To follow-on what @EmanuelP stated, the error `AttributeError: 'str' object has no attribute 'content'` is exactly because you treat report_url like it's some kind of response object; it's a string and strings don't have a `content` attribute. So, you'll need download the ZIP from report_url first.